# Scratch card odds

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to work out how to set up a scratch card system with a preset probability.

Lets say I have types going from 1-8 which corresponds to your chance of winning. So a type 8 card is the cheapest and has a 1 in 8 chance of winning.

Each card has three blocks and you can only reveal one for a prize.

Now if I understand this right, my type 1 cards will have a prize under each block, my type 3 cards will have one block with a prize, and my type 4 cards will have 2 blocks with no prize, and one block with a 75% chance of containing a prize.

I work it out like this:

One block has a prize, that's 0.33333 odds to select that block. I want a 0.25 chance total 0.25/0.333 = 0.75, so the prize block has a 75% chance.

Does this hold up, or have I done my math wrong?

Comment: That works, but you could equally decide to have your type 4 card to have a $0.25$ probability of all blocks having a prize and a $0.75$ probability that none have a prize, and this would reduce the opportunity for disputes that more than one block had been revealed.